# Trying to download all image files from an AWS s3 bucket subfolder into a file on cloud9 IDE

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, boto3, aws-cloud9

I found this code online but I am unable to change it to get the images downloaded into a specified folder.

```py
    import boto3
    import os

    def download_all_objects_in_folder():
        s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
        my_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket('images')
        objects = my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='pets/cats/')
        for obj in objects:
            path, filename = os.path.split(obj.key)
            my_bucket.download_file(obj.key, filename)
```

Comment: What is the error you are facing ? Also what do you mean by unable to change it ?

Comment: What happens when you run it? Are you getting any errors? For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)